# GitHub - how to implement multi-tier branch protection rules?

Tags: github, branch, branching-and-merging

We have a repo that already has a standard branch protection rule of requiring at least 1 approval. I'm curious to know if there's any way to setup a multi-tier rule for this branch. Specifically, what I'm trying to enable is: if certain files are modified in the pull request, I would want at least 2 approvals before merge. It doesn't seem like the UI makes this possible, but I'd be interested to know if - perhaps through Actions - there is a clever way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen how this can be done in the UI either. One way you could achieve this though is to create a branch protection rule that requires a status check to pass, and make a Github Action that runs a script checking on the number of approvals the request currently has using the [Github context object](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts). Then you can get as granular as you like in the script.  Something similar to how gautamkrishnar manages limiting pull requests to particular branches [here (archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20220621222726/https://github.community/t/improvement-suggestion-settings-branch-pattern-that-can-only-merge-to-target-branch-pattern/171870).